# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4'

Tags: python, encoding, ascii

I permanently get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I already tried

1. `x.encode("ascii", "ignore")`
2. `x.encode("utf-8")`
3. `x.decode("utf-8")`

However, nothing works.

Comment: `u'\xe4'.encode('ascii','ignore')` works fine for me. We need more context to see what the real problem is.

Comment: #2 also "works" in that it produces a result w/o error; can't say if it is the desired result.

Answer (score 15):

You have to discover in which encoding is this character at the source.

I guess this is ISO-8859-1 (european languages), in which case it's "ä", but you should check. It could also be cyrillic or greek.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1 for a complete list of characters in this encoding.

Using this information, you can ask Python to convert it :

In Python 2.7

```
>>> s = '\xe4'
>>> t = s.decode('iso-8859-1')
>>> print t
ä
>>> for c in t:
...   print ord(c)
...
228
>>> u = t.encode('utf-8')
>>> print u
ä
>>> for c in bytes(u):
...   print ord(c)
...
195
164
```

String `t` is internally encoded in ISO-8859-1 in Python. String `u` is internally encoded in UTF-8, and that character takes 2 bytes in UTF-8. Notice also that the `print` instruction "knows" how to display these different encodings.

Comment: Is there another solution for python3?

Answer (score 0):

I want to use Python to send an email.
connection.login(user=myEmail, password=myPass)

Unfortunately I used a "ä" in my password.

Now I have the error decribed above. Encoding it with utf-8 doen't solve it.

```
response = encode_base64(initial_response.encode('ascii'), eol='')
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe4' in position 21: ordinal not in range(128)

Any Idea?

Comment: You should post this as a question, not as an answer.