# ASCII and UTF problems in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, urllib, python-unicode

I have a **dataframe** where I have symbols such as %22 and I am trying to replace them using urllib. For other files this code worked perfectly but for some reason I am getting this error. Any ideas how I can fix this. As far as I know I am using utf-8.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Data\Genres\cleanedGenreArtistSong.csv',engine = 'python', encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
df['Song'] = df['Song'].apply(lambda x:urllib.unquote(x).decode('utf8') )
```

The error I am getting is:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is a snapshot of my dataframe:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjx5G.png)

Comment: Have look
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592988/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xe4

Comment: Is it possible to use .encode('ascii','ignore') on a dataframe?